# Scraping html tables with python3 and bs4 not working

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm  trying to obtain the main table in this website:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen as upen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

my_url="http://www.expansion.com/mercados/cotizaciones/indices/ibex35_I.IB.html"

sauce=upen(my_url)
table=soup.find('table')
table_rows=table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
td=tr.find_all('td')
print(td)
```

I have been attempting for a while but I have not been able to scrape the table properly. It is my first attempt at bs, maybe the table in question is too complicated. Any suggestion or advice is hugely appreciated. 
I apologise in advance if the question is dumb.

Just to clarify, I should be getting a table that looks like this:

Valor   Último  Var. %  Var.    Ac. % año   Máx.    Mín.    Vol.    Capitaliz.  Hora
ABERTIS 16,350  -0,40   -0,07   26,05   16,395  16,315  140.847 16.193  09:32
ACCIONA 83,150  -0,45   -0,38   18,90   83,300  82,850  8.486   4.761   09:31
ACERINOX    12,160  -1,10   -0,14   -3,53   12,320  12,150  58.275  3.357   09:32
ACS 35,880  -0,79   -0,28   21,37   36,055  35,815  28.698  11.290  09:33
AENA    171,450 -0,09   -0,15   35,42   171,500 170,700 4.876   25.718  09:32
AMADEUS IT GROUP    49,120  0,34    0,16    14,83   49,165  48,630  97.650  21.555  09:32
ARCELORMITTAL   19,765  -0,55   -0,11   -6,23   19,790  19,670  54.816  20.198  09:32
BANCO POPULAR   0,653   -1,06   -0,01   -28,87  0,662   0,652   4.537.116   2.741   09:33
BANCO SABADELL  1,808   -1,26   -0,02   39,19   1,827   1,805   1.603.476   10.154  09:33
BANKIA  1,034   -1,52   -0,02   9,29    1,044   1,032   2.630.931   11.909  09:33
BANKINTER   8,204   -1,25   -0,10   12,46   8,267   8,202   106.914 7.374   09:33
BBVA    7,369   -1,55   -0,12   18,47   7,425   7,361   2.112.122   49.136  09:33
CAIXABANK   4,148   -1,47   -0,06   34,15   4,200   4,145   1.440.359   24.811  09:33
CELLNEX TELECOM 17,880  0,03    0,00    31,16   17,880  17,770  113.987 4.142   09:33
DIA 5,525   -0,04   -0,00   18,44   5,527   5,476   213.782 3.439   09:32
ENAGAS  26,160  0,36    0,09    8,44    26,180  25,995  89.481  6.245   09:33
ENDESA  21,740  -0,09   -0,02   8,02    21,760  21,655  45.955  23.017  09:33
FERROVIAL   19,900  -0,82   -0,17   19,01   19,990  19,840  96.503  14.578  09:32
GAMESA  20,055  -1,43   -0,29   24,55   20,240  19,970  160.129 13.660  09:33
GAS NATURAL 21,905  -0,32   -0,07   22,31   21,910  21,760  65.387  21.920  09:32
GRIFOLS 24,555  -0,02   -0,00   30,06   24,620  24,490  24.074  10.464  09:32
IAG 6,840   0,28    0,02    33,36   6,854   6,764   894.978 14.590  09:33
IBERDROLA   6,992   -0,47   -0,03   14,68   6,999   6,968   653.999 45.168  09:33
INDITEX 35,880  -0,26   -0,09   11,73   35,900  35,750  91.546  111.825 09:33
INDRA   12,140  -0,37   -0,05   16,62   12,140  12,095  24.100  2.145   09:32
MAPFRE  3,133   -0,79   -0,03   8,03    3,159   3,129   113.953 9.648   09:33
MEDIASET    12,240  -0,29   -0,03   14,35   12,255  12,170  52.889  4.121   09:33
MELIÁ HOTELS    13,340  -0,52   -0,07   20,40   13,360  13,305  15.800  3.064   09:31
MERLIN PROP.    11,275  -0,22   -0,03   9,15    11,305  11,210  41.484  5.297   09:29
RED ELÉCTRICA   19,785  0,33    0,07    11,84   19,805  19,665  123.146 10.705  09:33
REPSOL  14,985  -0,17   -0,03   11,66   15,015  14,920  165.997 22.424  09:33
SANTANDER   5,784   -1,36   -0,08   18,93   5,820   5,777   3.353.148   84.344  09:33
TECNICAS REUNIDAS   34,460  -0,83   -0,29   -9,98   34,700  34,420  23.015  1.926   09:32
TELEFÓNICA  10,000  -0,74   -0,07   13,38   10,015  9,971   583.065 50.378  09:33
VISCOFAN    53,950  -0,17   -0,09   15,15   54,040  53,750  8.403   2.514   09:33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url="http://www.expansion.com/mercados/cotizaciones/indices/ibex35_I.IB.html"

r = requests.get(my_url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
table=soup.find('table')
table_rows=table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td=tr.find_all('td')
    print(td)
```

i did this way. 
Please instal html5lib and requests using pip

### edit 2

Change for this

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
 table=soup.find('table', id='listado_valores')
 print(table.text)
```

Is it? Seems pretty close.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am afraid it's still not doing what I expect. It should bring all fields in the table, while doing this I can only get what seems to be the first row.

Comment: It does seem pretty close!!! Thanks a lot. How would I go about obtaining the values separately? Can I do that?

Comment: Looking fast, inside table id listado_valores there is <tr> with the info you need.

Comment: You can work with "for" to just after the soup.find table. Seems this table always show the same quantity of stocks, I think its the best way...